# Adding something to an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

so im trying to the add something to an arraylist but everytime i use the .add  it gives me an error that i dont know why it is occuring.The error is occurring in artistaMusica.add(newTag).
Does anyone know why is it wrong ?

Heres the error :

```
'add(pt.ulusofona.aed.deisiRockstar2021.Song)' in 'java.util.ArrayList' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'
```

Heres my code:

```
 public static void ADD_TAGS(ArrayList<Song> artistaMusica,String artista,String newTag){

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        

        String tempArtist = "";

        for(int i = 0 ; i < artistaMusica.size() ; i++) {
            tempArtist = artistaMusica.get(i).getnomeArtista().replace("']", "").replace("['", "").trim();

            if  (artista.equals(tempArtist)) {

                artistaMusica.add(newTag);

                System.out.println(artista+" | " + newTag );
            }
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("(took "+(end-start)+" ms)\n");
    }
```

Comment: You’re trying to add a String type to a List of type Song.

Comment: So how i can i add The String newTag to the arraylist ?

Comment: You can’t. If the String newTag is an attribute of the class Song, then you can do artistaMusica.add(new Song(newTag)). However, the class Song might have other attributes that you would need to account for. Basically you can only add a Song to the array list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you try to find a matching song in the input list and then add the new tag to this song, NOT to the list of songs (providing that there is a getter `List<String> getTags()` in class `Song`).

```java
public static void addTag(ArrayList<Song> artistaMusica, String artista, String newTag) {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (Song song : artistaMusica) {
        String artistName = song.getnomeArtista()
                    .replace("']", "").replace("['", "").trim();

        if (artista.equals(artistName)) {
            // add tag to the matching song
            song.getTags().add(newTag);

            System.out.println(artista+" | " + newTag );
        }
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("(took " + (end - start) + " ms)\n");
}
```

Comment: The way you say it helps but it kept giving errors because the function is static , and when i put the song.getTags() static it stop to recognize the add(newTag);. The error when is non-static : Non-static method 'getTags()' cannot be referenced from a static context. And the error when i put the song.getTags() static  :  Cannot resolve method 'add' in 'String'

Comment: There is an assumption in my answer: _providing that there is a getter `List<String> getTags()` in class Song_  If you store tags per song as a string, the getter may look like `String getTags()` and then it would be better to have a method in `Song` class to append a tag `song.addTag(String newTag);`  Please keep in mind that you have not provided full information about your classes and therefore it is impossible to provide 100% copy-paste-ready solution for your specific case.